# Server side callback function ajax web service asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, callback

I'm using Web Service to handle ajax request in my project. I need to call a server side function to count users online when a new request is proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call Server side method into Client side then,you have to transform this method as a PageMethod and then call this method i.e `GetOnlineUser()` from client side code; i.e. using JavaScript.

To enable the method as a PageMethod, add the attribute `[WebMethod]` on top of the GetOnlineUser method in .aspx code behind file.

if you are using asp.Net membership provider then simply call  `Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()`.

And if you are not using membership you have to implement your own custom counter...